# Using regex iterator with char *

Tags: c++, regex, string, iterator

I'm trying to read a file into a buffer and then use regex iterator. I know I can use a C++ string iterator with the regex iterator (constructor is `std::regex_iterator<std::string::iterator>`), but I'd like to avoid copying my buffer into a string and keep using low level functions to read the file (right now I'm using `open()` and `read()`).

```
struct stat buff;
int file = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
if(!file)
    cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
else if(fstat(file, &buff))
    cout << "Error" << endl;
else
{
    cout << (buff.st_size) << endl;
    char fr[buff.st_size+1];

    read(file, fr, buff.st_size); // using string::c_str() or string::data() didn't work
    fr[buff.st_size] = '\0';
    // then use regex iterator to iterate through matches
}
close(file);
```

I think that my options are to find a way to use `read()` with a C++ string instead of char * or a way to use the regex iterator on a char array. I could write one, but I'm also trying to keep my program as small as possible.

Is there a way I can do that? How can I use C++ string as C char * (for `read()`)?

Comment: There should be a form that allows `const char *`. Just make sure the buffer is null terminated as it uses its strlen() to create a stopping point.

Comment: string::data should have worked and I think is the proper way to do it - pre-allocate the string before read and use it as a buffer. What kind of error do you get when trying to use string::data?

Comment: As an example Boost regex has one of these forms `regex_match(const charT* str,const basic_regex <charT, traits>& e,match_flag_type flags = match_default);` likewise search and replace. I've used it before. Mostly I use the string iterator begin/end.

Comment: You have to pre-allocate the string buffer since I don't think read() will do that for you. Your better off passing the buffer ptr to the regex routines. Or, you could just create a string from the buffer.

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy The problem with `std::string::data()` is that it is a `const char*`.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `std::regex_iterator<char*>`. A pointer is a fine bidirectional iterator on it's own. Also, avoid allocating a large char array on the stack, it might overflow. Instead, use the heap:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> fr = new char[buff.st_size + 1];
```

Comment: I totally agree with allocating from the _heap_ instead of the stack. Stack problems are very hard to pinpoint.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a `std::string` you can simply pass the address of the first element of the string to the `read()` function like this:

```
    struct stat buff;
    int file = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if(!file)
        cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
    else if(fstat(file, &buff))
        cout << "Error" << endl;
    else
    {
        cout << (buff.st_size) << endl;
//      char fr[buff.st_size+1];

        std::string fr; // use a std::string
        fr.resize(buff.st_size); // resize it to create internal buffer
        read(file, &fr[0], fr.size()); // this should work

//      read(file, fr, buff.st_size); 
//      fr[buff.st_size] = '\0';
        // then use regex iterator to iterate through matches
    }
    close(file);
```